# unrecognized selector sent to instance - How to fix: Error Loading picture from photo album

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, unrecognized-selector

I get the following error when trying to load picture from photo album, I'm not sure why: unrecognized selector sent to instance Below is my code and below is part of my error stack:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber extent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x60000022d440' *** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010efe21e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294 1 libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x000000010d1e9031 objc_exception_throw + 48 2 CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010f063784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132 3 CoreFoundation 0x000000010ef64898 ___forwarding_ + 1432 4
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010eff5d28 forwarding_prep_1_ + 120 5 CoreImage
>   0x000000010daecf17 -[CISepiaTone outputImage] + 152

Please find my source code below:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class ViewController: UIViewController,  UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    //outlet for image to be filtered
    @IBOutlet weak var imageToFilter: UIImageView!

    //outlet for slider to manipulate intensity as slider is dragged
    @IBOutlet weak var filterIntensity: UISlider!

    //property to store UIImage containing the image selected by user from photo album
    var currentImage: UIImage!

    //context from CoreImage Framework to handle rendering of the image for Wakanda Filter
    var imageContext: CIContext!

    //CoreImage Filter to store filters selected by the user
    var currentImageFilters: CIFilter!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //objects of coreContext and coreFilterd
        imageContext = CIContext()
        currentImageFilters = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")

        //title to appear on nav
        title = "Wakanda Filter"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(importPictureFromAlbum))
    }

    //action to update UI when user increases or decreases intensity
    @IBAction func intensityValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        processImageWithFilter()
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo  info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let imageSelected = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)

        currentImage = imageSelected

        //setting imported image as value to Filter object then manipulating
        let initialImageForFilters = CIImage(image: currentImage)
        currentImageFilters.setValue(initialImageForFilters, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        //calling on method to process the image
        processImageWithFilter()
    }

    func processImageWithFilter(){
        currentImageFilters.setValue(filterIntensity.value, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        if let computerGeneratedImage = imageContext.createCGImage(currentImageFilters.outputImage!, from: currentImageFilters.outputImage!.extent){
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: computerGeneratedImage)
            self.imageToFilter.image = processedImage
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    //objective c method to control method for selector how to import picture from album
    @objc func importPictureFromAlbum(){
        //creating an object of UIImagePickerController class (will allow editing of images too by modifying Info.plist
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        //allow editing of the image
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        //assigning delegate
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance, this happens when I select a picture from photo album, apparently on this line of code: navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(importPictureFromAlbum))

Answer (score 4):

The `CISepiaTone` filter expects two parameters:

> inputImage: A CIImage object whose display name is Image.
>
> inputIntensity: An NSNumber object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeScalar and whose display name is Intensity.

Your error is from this line:

```
currentImageFilters.setValue(filterIntensity.value, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

Either change the value to be the image or change the key to `kCIInputIntensityKey`.

Given that you set the image earlier, you probably want to change the key on this line.

```
currentImageFilters.setValue(filterIntensity.value, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //outlet for image to be filtered
    @IBOutlet weak var imageToFilter: UIImageView!
    //outlet for slider to manipulate intensity as slider is dragged
    @IBOutlet weak var filterIntensity: UISlider!

    //property to store UIImage containing the image selected by user from photo album
    var currentImage: UIImage!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    //context from CoreImage Framework to handle rendering of the image for Wakanda Filter
    var imageContext: CIContext!

    //CoreImage Filter to store filters selected by the user
    var currentImageFilters: CIFilter!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //objects of coreContext and coreFilterd
        imageContext = CIContext()
        currentImageFilters = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")

        //title to appear on nav
        title = "Wakanda Filter"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(importPictureFromAlbum))
    }

    //action to update UI when user increases or decreases intensity
    @IBAction func intensityValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        processImageWithFilter()
    }


@objc func importPictureFromAlbum(){
        //creating an object of UIImagePickerController class (will allow editing of images too by modifying Info.plist

        //allow editing of the image
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        //assigning delegate
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }

    func processImageWithFilter(){
        currentImageFilters.setValue(filterIntensity.value, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        if let computerGeneratedImage = imageContext.createCGImage(currentImageFilters.outputImage!, from: currentImageFilters.outputImage!.extent){
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: computerGeneratedImage)
            self.imageToFilter.image = processedImage
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ,UINavigationControllerDelegate  {
         func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo  info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let imageSelected = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)

        self.currentImage = imageSelected

        //setting imported image as value to Filter object then manipulating
        let initialImageForFilters = CIImage(image: currentImage)
        currentImageFilters.setValue(filterIntensity.value, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

        //calling on method to process the image
        self.processImageWithFilter()
    }


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: thank you, rmaddy made corrections, fixed and working now

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers that explain what was wrong. Please add some useful description.

Comment: @rmaddy okay i will add next time to descript answer. thanks rmaddy for your nice suggestion

Comment: You need to edit this answer. 1. There is no indication of what you changed. 2. The mistake hasn't even been fixed in this answer.